# How to target class as well as "target.is"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Im using the following code to change a custom cursor's size when hovering on anything "clickable". Currently Im using `target.is` to target links and span elements ('a, span'), I want to either also be able to target specific elements by class for example the hamburger menu icon ".menu-button", OR if its possible just target anything clickable, which would be the easiest solution by far but im unsure if its even possible.

Thanks!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {

  const cursor = $('.custom-cursor');
  const target = $(event.target);
  
  // update position of cursor
  cursor.css('left', e.clientX-10).css('top', e.clientY-10);
  
  const isLinkTag = target.is('a,span');
  const isHovered = cursor.hasClass('hoveredCursor');
  
  // toggle the cursor class if necessary 
  if(isLinkTag && !isHovered) {
  
    cursor.addClass('hoveredCursor');

  } else if(!isLinkTag && isHovered) {
  
    cursor.removeClass('hoveredCursor');
  
  }
  
})
 
$(document).mouseleave(function(e) {

  const cursor = $('.custom-cursor');
  cursor.hide()

});

$(document).mouseenter(function(e) {

  const cursor = $('.custom-cursor');
  cursor.show()

});
});
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you provided the HTML too.

Comment: `event.target` should be `e.target` --> `function(e) {` wrong variable usage....

Comment: the HTML is just <div class="custom-cursor"></div>

Comment: @epascarello the code is working, i just need to figure out how to target classes OR anything that is clickable

Comment: @gjjr it works for the browser you are running it in, but does not mean it is correct. You correctly use `e` in the other places in that function.

Comment: @epascarello cool ill update that then, do you know how to change `const isLinkTag = target.is('a,span');` so I can target classes aswell?

Comment: so add the selectors? `is(".foo,.bar,a,span")`??

Comment: @epascarello yeh tried that already, it doesnt work if you just add the classes in the brackets after `target.is`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for performance reasons, you shouldn't use absolute positioning with left/top values for something like this. Position the cursor via `transform: translate(...)` instead and it will immediately be more performant.

I also think you don't need the check for `isHovered` at all.

This demo also shows that adding the class selectors to `is(...)`, as suggested in the comments, is actually enough:

**Update:** I updated the code to include anything with an onclick attribute and added a check for any registered click events

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#a-button').click(function() {
    //...
  });

  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {

    const cursor = $('.custom-cursor');
    const target = $(e.target);

    // update position of cursor
    cursor.css({
      'transform': 'translate(' + (e.clientX - 10) + 'px,' + (e.clientY - 10) + 'px)'
    });

    const isLinkTag = target.is('a,span,.a-specific-class,[onclick]');
    const hasClickEvent = !!$._data(target.get(0), 'events')?.click;

    // toggle the cursor class if necessary 
    if (isLinkTag || hasClickEvent) {
      cursor.addClass('hoveredCursor');
    } else {
      cursor.removeClass('hoveredCursor');
    }
  })

  $(document).mouseleave(function(e) {

    const cursor = $('.custom-cursor');
    cursor.hide()

  });

  $(document).mouseenter(function(e) {

    const cursor = $('.custom-cursor');
    cursor.show()

  });
});
```

```css
* {
  cursor: none;
}

.custom-cursor {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}

.hoveredCursor {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-cursor"></div>

<a href="#">I'm a link!</a>
<br><br>
<span>I'm a span</span>

<p class="a-specific-class">I'm a paragraph with a specific class</p>

<button onclick="console.log()">I have a click event</button>

<button id="a-button">I have a jQuery click event</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, although unfortunately it didnt work for me. Changing the position of the cursor using transform made the cursor very laggy, and for whatever reason using classes after "target.is" doesnt work for me.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how to help you now, as it obviously works in the code snippet?

Comment: Yeh it must be conflicting with other code on my site, thanks for your help anyway!